# JS Object to Swift Struct

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am having difficulties parsing data (JSON-like I get from endpoint) to Swift structs. As it seems data I get from the endpoint is not a valid JSON (at least not all of it looking at the structure of *object = (...)*), so I can't decode `ListStruct`.

Should I parse it another way? Any advice much appreciated

Structs I prepared are:

```
struct Response:Codable {
    let message:String?
    let list:ListStruct?
    let error:Bool?
}

struct ListStruct:Codable {
    let object1:[Object1]?
    let object2:[Object2]?
    let object3:[Object3]?
}

struct Object1:Codable {
id:Int?
name:String?
}
...
```

Example of data I get from endpoint:

```
["message": <null>, "list": {
    object1 =     (
                {
            id = 1;
            name = "testing1";
        }
    );
    object2 =     (
                {
            files =             (
            );
            id = 1;
            name = "testing2-1";
            photos =             (
            );
        },
                {
            files =             (
            );
            id = 2;
            name = "testing2-2";
            photos =             (
            );
            systemId = 8;
        }
    );
    object3 =     (
                {
            id = 6;
            name = "testing3-1";
        },
                {

            id = 13;
            name = "testing3-2";
        }
    );
}, "error": 0]
```

---

EDIT

How I am trying do decode:

```
if let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response?.self, from: "\(response!)".data(using: .utf8)! ) {
                        print("\(result)")
                    }
```

Error I am getting:

```
Error: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 6." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 6.})))
```

Comment: Paste your json code [here](https://app.quicktype.io/).

Comment: This is how `JSON` looks on `Xcode console`, there is no problem with that. Tell us the error you are getting while `decoding` it. Use the above link by @dahiya_boy to generate your model classes.

Comment: This seems like valid json. What is the error you're getting, and what is in Object1, 2, and 3?

Comment: The output is neither JSON nor a collection type *description*. It's something out of both.

Comment: "Example of data I get from endpoint:": Where did you print that? If it was really JSON, seems to that is has already been parsed through JSONSerialization, and mixing Swift Dictionary, and "Objective-C" NSArray & NSDictionary. What is `response` exactly? Could you show the lines where you get it? I'd say that the method you use is already parsing it.

Comment: The cause of the error is most likely the nonsensical String Interpolation `"\(response!)"` which of course does not produce  valid JSON. Where does `response` come from?

Comment: Why don't you print the `response` variable and add (part of) the output to the question

Comment: use decodeIfPresent in your model class and set default value if that value not available.   Exaple:   name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: "name") ?? ""

Comment: @VimalkumarN.M. `decodeIfPresent` is pointless if *The given data was not valid JSON*.

Comment: @d324223 can you post the code where you create `response` object?
If you are getting this from a API as `Data` type you don't need to do anything and pass it to `JSONDecode()` otherwise depends on how it's generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you are passing the wrong data object by creating using string interpolation. If the `response` type is `Data` then you don't need to recreate it again in the below line,

```
if let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response?.self, from: "\(response!)".data(using: .utf8)! ) {
```

Try to pass the `response` as it is. Shown below,

```
if let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response?.self, from: response!) {
```

---

Here is a complete testable example where the correct data object is created using the `json` in question and `error` type in `Response` is changed from `Optional` `Bool` to `Int`,

```
struct Response:Codable {
    let message:String?
    let list:ListStruct?
    let error: Int?
}

struct ListStruct: Codable {
    let object1:[Object1]?
    let object2:[Object2]?
    let object3:[Object3]?
}

struct Object1: Codable {
    var id:Int?
    var name:String?
}

struct Object2: Codable {
    var id:Int?
    var name:String?
    var systemId: Int?
}

struct Object3: Codable {
    var id:Int?
    var name:String?
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let data = """
{"message": null,

"list": {
"object1": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "testing1"
}
],
"object2" :     [
{
"files" :             [
],
"id" : 1,
"name" : "testing2-1",
"photos" :             [
]
},
{
"files" :            [
],
"id" : 2,
"name" : "testing2-2",
"photos" :             [
],
"systemId" : 8
}
],
"object3" :     [
{
"id" : 6,
"name" : "testing3-1",
},
{

"id" : 13,
"name" : "testing3-2",
}
]
},

"error": 0
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

if let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response?.self, from: data) {
        result.list?.object1?.forEach({ obj in
            print(obj.name)
        })
        result.list?.object2?.forEach({ obj in
            print(obj.name)
        })
        result.list?.object3?.forEach({ obj in
            print(obj.name)
        })
}
```

**Output:**

```
Optional("testing1")
Optional("testing2-1")
Optional("testing2-2")
Optional("testing3-1")
Optional("testing3-2")
```